# AJAX in email body?

Tags: javascript, ajax, email

Is there a way to load dynamic content into an email when it is rendered? Recently I had to rebook a flight and the booking agent told me to close out of the email on my phone so they could give me a new itinerary. How are they piping dynamic content into the email? AJAX? I thought JS didn't work in emails.

Comment: Most popular email clients block Javascript now so no.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't sound like a programming question. It seems better suited to [Super User](http://superuser.com/), however, I suspect that you'd have have provide a more information if you want any anyone to provide an explanation as to what's going on (e.g. what kind of phone and email client are you using).

Answer (score 3):

AJAX does not run in most email clients - it's a security risk. The only thing I can imagine is that they can change pictures. Pictures are usually reloaded from the server everytime you open the email. Other than that, the person talking to you just might not understand how emails actually work.