# Make ajax call from email

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, email

Is it possible to make ajax call to my server from email. For example, lets suppose I send an email to a gmail address. When the person opens the email, he can click a link which in result will make an ajax call to my server. Is this possible or does cross domain restriction will not allow this?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23259214/ajax-in-email-body

Comment: Yeah i think Mail servers such as Gmail are preventing cross site scripting and they'll report your mail as spam!

Comment: Also most email clients use a very old version of the browser, probably so old that AJAX had not been invented when these versions were written

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Mail clients usually support html, but not ajax/javascript. Gmail implements something called "one click actions", which might do what you want. But this doesn't work with other email providers and mail clients. https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/one-click-action

Comment: @HåkenLid I wanted to have a quiz with yes/no answers. When user click yes/no I wanted to submit this via ajax for each answer.

Comment: Sounds like a neat idea. But it's not really what email is made for. I suspect it is quite hard to make something that works consistently across different mail clients, if it's possible at all. Have you looked for any ready made 3rd party services that can do quizzes over email?

Answer (score -1):

it's posible, use dataType=jsonp in your ajax request

```
<script>
 $.ajax({
   url: 'a_cross_domain_url',
   dataType: 'jsonp'
 });
</script>
```