# PHP link with post instead of get

Tags: php

I am sending a link via email:

```
$to = $email;
                        $subject = "Reset your password";
                        $txt = "Hello " . $user . ", <br><br>Click here to reset your password <a href='http://example.com/reset-password?email=" . $email . "'>Reset Password</a>";

                        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";

                        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";

                        $headers .= "From: webmaster@example.com";

                        if(mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers))
                        {
                            $returnArray['error_message'] = "Email has been sent.";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $returnArray['error_message'] = "There is an issue with sending an email";
                        }
```

Right now I am passing the email as $_GET, but I am trying to get it as $_POST, I have tried using javascript like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function DoPost(userEmail){
      $.post("http://example.com/reset-password/", { email: userEmail } );
   }

</script>
```

and then on my link have this:

```
$txt = "Hello " . $user . ", <br><br>Click here to reset your password <a href='javascript:DoPost(" . $email . ");'>Reset Password</a>";
```

But then I get the email, it turns out like this:

```
<a rel="nofollow">Reset Password</a>
```

The link does not appear in the email, is it possible to do what I am trying to do, create a post link in an email?

Comment: You can't do AJAX in email https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23259214/ajax-in-email-body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most email clients do not support form submissions or any form of Javascript. And you should always assume that people block scripts/images from emails by default. Clicking a link in an email will usually open the user's web browser and redirect them to the page - this way you can attach a query string with `?foo=bar` and access these parameters via `$_GET`.

If you absolutely must retrieve these parameters in `$_POST`, for whatever reason, you could redirect the user to a form that auto-submits as POST via Javascript (and pre-fill some hidden inputs to have your parameters passed through).

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap it with `form` html tag instead of using `a href` link with get parameter:

```
$txt = "Hello " . $user . ", <br><br>Click here to reset your password 
<form action='http://example.com/reset-password' method='post'>
  <input type='hidden' name='email' value='".$email."'>  
   <button type='submit'  value='Submit'>Reset Password</button>
</form>";
```